# PostgreSQL - Select value depending on other table's value

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables, one called "users" other called "referral". Every user has a code associated with it and this is how they look:

```
USERS TABLE

user_id  name    ref_type   other_referral
 1       Ely      friend         SA0987
 2       Sandra   page  
 3       Karla    friend         EC0000
 4       Tania    email
```

```
REFERRAL TABLE

user_id   code
  1      EC0000
  2      SA0987
```

I want to select everything from the users table, but if the referral matches with `friend` and `other_referral` is not empty, then I need instead of that alpha numerical code, I want the name of the user, which can be associated from the table `REFERRAL`.

EXAMPLE:

```
id  name    ref_type    other_referral
1   Ely      friend        Sandra
2   Sandra   page   
3   Karla    friend         Ely
4   Tania    email
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LEFT JOIN` from `users` via `referral` back to `users` to find the friend.

```
SELECT u.user_id AS id, u.name, u.ref_type, coalesce(f.name, u.other_referral) AS other_referral
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN referral r
  ON u.ref_type = 'friend'
    AND u.other_referral = r.code
LEFT JOIN users f
  ON r.user_id = f.user_id
ORDER BY id;
```

I have added a fallback to the alphanumeric code via `coalesce` in case there's not a friend with that code or there is a different `ref_type` which can have a code, too.

Here is the [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c23413a60a549edf480dd30a57774a67).

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you for your help!! :)